# Get the library via dependency code using bash command

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to make a library for projects using gradle and maven.

To test that if it is possible for the gradle to download it via the dependency code in the bintray, I need something like a bash command to see if the request gets the file from bintray or not.

**TL; DR**

Is there a **terminal command** for gradle to get a dependency like 
`./gradlew dependecies 'com.example.lib:module:2.0.0'` ?

Comment: Why don't you simply write a simple build script with that library as dependency, and a class that uses that library and see if the project compiles with gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Download it's `.pom` file**

You can download the library `pom` file from maven. All the library dependencies are in a `pom` file. Gradle uses this file to fetch the dependencies